# Process protocol, deferred, and command line input

Tags: python, twisted

I have a wrapper script with a class derived from `protocol.ProcessProtocol` which calls an external piece of code. What I want is to be able to interact with said piece of code via the wrapper's command line.  The idea is that this wrapper will be wrapping several pieces of code and provide a (simple?) unified interface to all of them.  Note that there is no need for networking within this application.

I am very new to Twisted but I am assuming that I need to write a [deferred](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/gendefer.html) function that reads `stdin`, parse it for sanity (whatever that means for my application), and then called `transport.write(sane_command)`.

**Does anyone know of an example of a deferred parsing the command line for input?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from here [How can I use a raw_input with twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143311/how-can-i-use-a-raw-input-with-twisted)

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.2.0/twisted/conch/stdio.py
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/stdin.py

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code (based from the [code of Jp Calderone](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.2.0/twisted/conch/stdio.py)) I came up with for posterity.

**Criticism is welcome**

---

```
import os
import tty
import sys
import termios

from pprint import pprint, pformat

from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio
from twisted.python import log

from twisted.conch.insults.insults import ServerProtocol
from twisted.conch.recvline import HistoricRecvLine
from twisted.conch.recvline import RecvLine

try:
    from fabulous.color import fg256
    _format_prompt = lambda x: fg256(63, x).as_utf8
except ImportError:
    _format_prompt = lambda x: x


class Fubar(HistoricRecvLine):

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Connection lost because', pformat(reason)
        reactor.stop()

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if line == "quit" or line == "exit" or line == "q":
            self.terminal.loseConnection()
        self.terminal.write('echo: %s' % (pformat(line)))
        self.terminal.nextLine()
        self.terminal.write(self.ps[self.pn])

    def connectionMade(self):
        """Called after a connection has been established."""
        pprint(self.ps)
        self.ps = (_format_prompt('echo> '), '...')
        RecvLine.connectionMade(self)
        self.historyLines = []
        self.historyPosition = 0
        t = self.terminal
        self.keyHandlers.update({t.UP_ARROW: self.handle_UP,
                                 t.DOWN_ARROW: self.handle_DOWN})


def runWithProtocol(klass):
    fd = sys.__stdin__.fileno()
    oldSettings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    tty.setraw(fd)
    try:
        p = ServerProtocol(klass)
        stdio.StandardIO(p)
        reactor.run()
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, oldSettings)
        os.write(fd, "\r\x1bc\r")


def main(argv=None):
    log.startLogging(file('child.log', 'w'))
    runWithProtocol(Fubar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [ndpu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1099876/ndpu)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15932008/232794) is accepted as their answer provided the missing link I needed.